# Android Launcher Loading Problem

Tags: google-play-store, launcher, location-services, auto-start

I'm desperate, otherwise I wouldn't post this long type of post on this forum, cause whenever I have a problem, I just search it on Google and 99% of cases I find the solution, but this time, I'm helpless. I would really appreciate if someone has a solution to my problem,

I have a Infocus M2. It is an awesome phone, I'm really satisfied with it. I have it for 1 year now and I have never had a problem, everything worked perfectly (and is still working), but for 7 days something keeps popping up: it doesn't matter if I'm in a game, or on the internet or am I doing something on the phone, a black screen with text "**Location service**" and after that a white screen appears with a little text "**Launcher loading**..." and a circle that is loading, and I have no idea what is that. I can't do anything, I just have to wait like 1 minute for it to disappear. After that a new app automatically start installing from Google play store.

All this problem started when I install a free app "**[Task bucks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taskbucks.taskbucks&hl=en)**" from Google play store. and this app automatically install a app "**Key Chain**" After that I just loose control over my phone. Whenever it connects to internet it start downloading apps like DU Speed, Battery Doctor and some those apps automatically install that I uninstalled 1 month ago etc. It's really frustrating. Also, this happens, like one time in 1 hours. I really hate it.

### I have to mention a thing:

- Some times After the white screen disappears, Google App Store opens, at a shopping app called "Ali Express" (like it wants to install it or something), I had it installed only one time, but I uninstalled it 6 months ago.
- Key Chain does not remove by restore factory setting. that is automatically installed from [Task bucks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taskbucks.taskbucks&hl=en)

  **Note**: I know one Key Chain is default app but my phone has 3 key chain

## I have Attempts following steps to solve my problem:

1. Restore factory setting and deleted all third party apps 2 times but problem is still.
2. Run up to 4 antivirus apps but no luck
3. Change google account password
4. Boot my phone in safe mode and clear cache, clear defaults of some apps like: launcher, key chain, location service etc. and Reset app preferrnces.

**I'm sorry for the large post, but I wanted to be as specific as possible. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If you are really familiar with android phones, I would suggest you to do a hard reset, followed by flashing device with a new ROM ([Custom ROMs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/infocus-m810-custom-roms-tweaks-t3237260) or [stock ROM](https://androidmtk.com/download-infocus-stock-rom))

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for great solution but i am not familiar with android development and i dont know about Custom ROMs or stock ROM

Answer (score -1):

If your phone is rooted you can use **[Stubborn Trojan Killer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.security.stubborntrjkiller&hl=en)**.

Answer (score -1):

I pretty much had the same problem in my Micromax Canvas nitro.
After rooting and flashing a new rom, it's all fine now.
Hope same works for you too!